# After copying file, can't properly use len(var_name) to get the size of copied file?

Tags: python

I'm working through Learn Python The Hard Way and am curious why I can't check the size of the file that I have copied to.

Here is the amended script that I added to from the book.

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

# We could do these two lines of code in one line, how?
in_file = open(from_file)
in_data = in_file.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long\n\n" % len(in_data)

print "Does the output file exist? %r \n\n" % exists(to_file)

print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort.\n"
raw_input()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(in_data)
out_file2 = open(to_file) # Added this line
out_data = out_file2.read() # Added this line


print "Completed. The copied file is %r bytes long." % len(out_data)

in_file.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: @Thanatos It prints that the copied file is 0 bytes AFTER I copy it. I want to prove that it has been copied by showing that there are the same amount of bytes afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Files", or the in-memory classes and functions for dealing with files, will often [buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) data. This means that data is held is a temporary section of memory before being written to disk. This allows you to make many small calls to `write`, which the program will buffer and then write it to disk in one large write. This is quicker, because it is more efficient to send larger writes to the OS at a time. (The reverse is true as well: file classes will often buffer reads, because it is quicker to pull in a lot of data all at once than to constantly ask the OS for 1 byte at a time.)

However, if you re-open the file before allowing that buffer to actually write, then you will not see the writes, because they have no yet been written. This is your problem. Here:

```
# You open the file:
out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
# You request a write; it gets buffered, but not yet written.
out_file.write(in_data)
# You re-open the file:
out_file2 = open(to_file) # Added this line
# And read. Nothing has been written, so out_data is empty.
out_data = out_file2.read() # Added this line

# Later, when your program shuts down, out_file is closed,
# and as part of closing, writes the data.
```

If you want to use two file objects, you need to call `.close` on `out_file` before reading from `out_file2`. *However*, Python offers an easier way: the `with` statement will do this all for you:

```
with open(to_file, 'w') as out_file:
    # out_file will close when this with block is done.
    out_file.write(in_data)
# out_file now closed.

with open(to_file) as out_file2: # Added this line
    out_data = out_file2.read() # Added this line
# out_file2 now closed.
```

Note that `with` is good practice even for files opened for reading: every file opened (reading or writing) will use up "file descriptors" (references to open files) on almost any OS, and these file descriptors are limited.

Note that you can see that [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) is buffered by looking [it up in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> `open(name[, mode[, buffering]])`
>
> […]
>
> The optional buffering argument specifies the file’s desired buffer size: 0 means unbuffered, 1 means line buffered, any other positive value means use a buffer of (approximately) that size (in bytes). A negative buffering means to use the system default, which is usually line buffered for tty devices and fully buffered for other files. If omitted, the system default is used.

Comment: Ah, so it's very similar to C. I had a feeling that was it but I wanted to confirm with someone much more familiar with Python. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Pahjay: Ah! I've included a link to and a snippet from the relevant documentation that explains the default behavior. (You can change it, but in most cases, the default is what you want.)

Comment: @Pahjay : Yes, it's very similar to C because Python file handles are C filehandles wrapped up in a class that gives you a few extra goodies. This same logic applies to quite a few other things in Python that utilize standard C library stuff.

Answer (score 0):

That code doesn't really make sense.  You just wrote the file contents, so the size of those contents is exactly the length of what you wrote, i.e. `len(in_data)` instead of `len(out_data)`.  This saves re-opening the file and reading it again.

By the way, the reason you got 0 size was because you must do `out_file.close()` or at least `flush()` before reading the file.  Otherwise, with the code you had, you are reading while the write is still in cache, not actually on the filesystem yet.